# Check if a given coordinate lies in path of a ray (coordinate geometry)

Tags: analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

### [image]

As shown in the image I have two known coordinate pair A and B and few other known coordinate pairs (RED blob) on the graph.

I need to know if any of the other given coordinates fall in line of the ray created by coordinates A and B.

I need some mathematical formula or any appropriate way to know this.

I need to implement the same in code.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your third, unknown point is $C$. If $C-A=n(B-A)$, C is in the ray, where n represents an arbitrary real.

So, an even better way to think of that is to find the slope $\frac{x_b-x_a}{y_b-y_a}$ and see if it is equivalent to the slope $\frac{x_c-x_a}{y_c-y_a}$

Comment: Finding and comparing the slope is the simplest thing to implement in code and it fits my current scenerio. Do let me know if this method might fail in any specific conditions. Thanks!

Comment: It fails in the event that $C=A$, but other than that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute the coördinates $(x\mid y)\quad$ into $\begin{vmatrix}
x&y&1\\
11&10&1\\
37&16&1
\end{vmatrix}\quad$.

If the result is 0, then $(x\mid y)\quad$ is in the ray.

Answer (score 1):

Find the equation of the line in parametric vector form, so that at $t = 0$ we have Point A and at $t = 1$, we have Point B:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 11 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix}(1 - t) + \begin{bmatrix} 37 \\ 16 \end{bmatrix}t
$$

Then to check if some point $(x_0, y_0)$ lies on the ray, simply plug it into the system of equations and see if it is possible to **consistently** solve for some $t \geq 0$. For example, $(89, 28)$ lies on the ray, since:
$$
89 = 11(1 - t) + 37t = 26t + 11 \implies 26t = 78 \implies t = 3 \geq 0 \\
28 = 10(1 - t) + 16t = 6t + 10 \implies 6t = 18 \implies t = 3 \geq 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the red dot have co-ordinates $(x_r,y_r) $

Then collinearity is established by

$$ \frac{ y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a} =\frac{ y_b-y_r}{x_b-x_r }.$$

Comment: This looks simple and can be easily implemented in code, but I tried these coordinates A(11, 10), B(45, 10), R(50, 10) and as per your formula I got 0 and -0 which looks good enough, do let me know if there any scenarios where this might go wrong or would produce incorrect results. Thanks!!

Comment: This is elementary coordinate geometry cannot go wrong. In this example. you are taking a line parallel to x-axis. So,$ R(any coordinate,10) $ is okay. Likewise check for lines parallel to y-axis. $ (5,12), (5,22),(5,anything)         $